# When should words like "granny" and "mom" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, kinship-terms

I often come across the words *mom* and *Mom*, *granny* and *Granny*, *dad* and *Dad*. What's the difference? When is it suitable to use the capital letters at the beginning of these words?

Comment: 'My mom' is informal for 'my mother'; I would write 'Hi, Mom' if I was writing a note to my mother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're capitalized when they're used as names (proper nouns), and lowercase when they're common nouns. Ask yourself whether you could use the person's name in the same sentence; if so, capitalize. Let's say my mom's name is Naomi:

- "Hi, Mom!" (I'm speaking to her by name. I could also say "Hi, Naomi" (though it might be socially odd).)
- "Is it okay with your mom?" (I'm not using "mom" here as a name, but as a kind of thing. I wouldn't say "... with your Naomi.")

Comment: That's no different to the fact that we might represent someone saying 'Hi, John/Naomi